# Compinling HTTPD and OpenSSL From source, server string is wrong?

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, httpd

System has OpenSSL version 1.0.1e which is what's available in the CentOS 7 repo yet there are so many CVE's since then (2013)

Httpd is compile from source with

```
./configure --enable-so --enable-ssl --enable-cache-disk --enable-cache-socache --enable-deflate --with-mpm=prefork --enable-fpm --enable-cgi --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl/include --enable-ssl-static-lib-deps --enable-mods-static=ssl
```

Yet even after a restart the server ssl version shows:

```
curl --head http://localhost

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 14 Jul 2017 04:46:26 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.6.30 mod_myfixip/1.4
Location: XYZ
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires: Fri, 14 Jul 2017 04:46:26 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

But on closer inspection of the httpd binary, it looks to be compiled with 1.0.21 as expected:

```
^@ssl_engine_init.c^@AH02209: CA certificate: %s^@init_server^@chil^@TLSv1.2, ^@TLSv1.1, ^@TLSv1, ^@SSLv3, ^@SSLProxy^@with^@without^@AH03039: %i:^@OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017^@OpenSSL^@Init: ^@SSL_VERSION_INTERFACE^@SSL_VERSION_LIBRARY^@
```

Comment: CVE's are backported to CentOS packages, so looking at the version doesn't mean what you think it does, see [here](https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General#head-3dad8cb98ac535185e58e882a23ca4b096cbff2f) and [here](https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the manually compiled openssl "lib" path to "**envvars**" file or add it manually to **$LD_LIBRARY_PATH** yourself before starting httpd for httpd to use it instead of the system version.

**envvars** file is included in the bin directory of httpd and it is used by apachectl script too. It is made for this purpose.

that is:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/ssl/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

Comment: envvars is in fact only used by apachectl and won't be used by httpd if called directly.